# Webform - how do I change dateformat in mail

Tags: webforms, datetime

Module: Webform

The short date type is dd/mm/yy, so it appears correctly in the form (day/month/year)
But in the mail it is shown with month first. (month/day/year)

How can I change the date type in the mail?

Comment: Can you please post the Date field settings for your web form.

Comment: Hi Krishna
Where do I find the Date Field setting?

Comment: I use the module webform. When I make the Date component I can choose type: date. That will make the date in the webform. You can se it here: http://domusmedica.dk/Kontakt_form. I can not figure out how/where to change the output and the date in the mail

Answer (score 1):

Try go to admin/config/regional/date-time and set your site's Medium date type format.

Also, if the Medium format doesn't include at least a month, day, and year field, Webform will default to the American format of MM/DD/YYYY.

Webform uses the "medium" in e-mails and viewing submissions, though everywhere else (like a displaying the date component) it uses short for the order

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Verify the answer so that others may also know.